# Why does executor.map seem to not be increasing list index?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, concurrent.futures

Initially I had this code in a for loop, but with over 2000 api calls in total, it really bogged everything down. I began researching how to help this, and learned of concurrent.futures and parallels in general, and I do believe it will be better... if I can get it to increment.  I believe I am passing everything correctly, but clearly I'm not.  It seems to be calling the same index of the list over and over, and not iterating, or increasing by one.  Again, I am very new to parallels, so please be gentle. in the for loop, I was able to do

for i in range(length):

and that worked great to obtain the index of the list, and was dynamic, but since moving it to the function, it says i is undefined, which is why I am using array_value.  Also, I know the code is sloppy right now, I'm just trying to figure it out, then I'll clean it.

```
users_and_teams_list = []
team_display_name = []
length = len(users_list)-1
teams_list = []
#for i in range(length):
def process_members(user_list):
array_value = 0
TeamID = users_list[array_value]["id"]

graph_api_endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/"+TeamID+"/members"

access_token = get_token_for_service_principal(
  client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, tenantId=tenantId, scope=scope
  )
userData = get_data_using_token(userUrl, access_token)

#Set headers for the API request
headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

response = requests.get(graph_api_endpoint, headers=headers)
team_display_name.extend([users_list[array_value]["displayName"]])
if response.status_code == 200:
    teams_data = response.json().get("value", [])
    teams_list.extend(teams_data)
    users_and_teams_list.extend(team_display_name+teams_list)
    array_value = array_value + 1
  # Check for nextLink for pagination
    while "@odata.nextLink" in response.json():
        next_link = response.json()["@odata.nextLink"]

      # Make the next GET request to the nextLink for the next page
        response = requests.get(next_link, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
          teams_data = response.json().get("value", [])
          teams_list.extend(teams_data)
        else:
          print("Error:", response.status_code)
          print(response.text)
          break
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
print(TeamID + " was processed...")

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process_members, users_list)
```

***The results are:***

33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...
33089--75a3 was processed...

Whereas I expect a different TeamID for each iteration.

Comment: When you `map(process_members, users_list)`, what do you expect process_members() to receive as an argument? Would that not be the TeamID you are looking for? Why doesn't your function use that? It just gets [`array_value`], which is always `ID 0`, or `33089--75a3`.

Comment: I would prefer to use users_list[i][“id”] instead of the array_value, but I’m unsure what needs to be done to do that. I would expect the index to change each time, for each row of the list.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and show a [mcve] including, for example, imports.  Hard code data in a complete example that shows the problem instead of referencing data that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, hellork.  You gave me what I needed! I was trying to use users_list[i]["id"] in the function, but I needed user_list["id"]